# Is there anyway to set IPrincipal in signalr application

Tags: signalr-hub, iprincipal

We have used saml protection in Web application. I will pass claims as part of header to signalr. I want to read name claim and set IPrincipal in Signalr.

- I have tried by implementing Asp.net module and Set the context like below
  (sender as HttpApplication).Context.User = "My Logic"
  The value was set but not able to see that in signalr HubCallerContext.
- Tried with IUserIdProvider.
- Tried with OnBeforeConnect.

I have tried all the possible ways which i know, But no result.

Is there any alternative ways to set IPrincipal in Signalr ?